# SFMC Rest API - How to retrieve name or ID from response

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

how do I return the ID for the ExactTarget Enhanced FTP from this response:

```
{"page":1,"pageSize":2,"count":2,"items":[{"name":"Salesforce Objects & Reports","id":"XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX","locationTypeId":4},{"name":"ExactTarget Enhanced FTP","id":"XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX","locationTypeId":0,"relPath":"ExactTarget Enhanced FTP"}]}
```

I'm trying to create a File Transfer by API and need the ID.

I get null returned when using this code:

```
var resultString = String(resp.content);
   var ftpLocations = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
   var ftpLocationsName = ftpLocations.name;
   var ftpLocationsID = ftpLocations.dataExtractDefinitionId;

   Write(Stringify(ftpLocationsName));
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The id seems to be right there in the response payload you pasted?

Comment: thanks for responding - updated the question with more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to iterate through the payload.

**Arrays** will require you to provide the index of the object/item you want (e.g. items[0] gets the first object)
**Objects** usually require a key to access the associated value. (e.g. items[0].name gets the name value from the object in the first object in the items array)

Which all together means to get the name/id from the first object in the JSON returned from your API call is to:

```javascript
var ftpLocationsName = ftpLocations.items[0].name
var ftpLocationsID = ftpLocations.items[0].id
```

You can then wrap that in a for loop to get it for each object in the array:

```javascript
var items = ftpLocations.items
for (i=0;i<items.length();i++) {
  var ftpLocationsName = ftpLocations.items[i].name
  var ftpLocationsID = ftpLocations.items[i].id
}
```

Which will iterate through each record and assign the value to the variable inside the loop.

Comment: Just to add to this, I wasn't sure if the final item returned would always be ExactTarget Enhanced FTP so I broke the loop if it was found, added 1 to i, then retrieved ftpLocations.items[i].name and ID The above and https://ampscript.xyz/tips-and-tricks/how-to-use-loops-with-server-side-javascript-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/ were helpful.